# COMPSs Monitor doesn't show any application

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hpc, compss

I am running with COMPSs the Increment application shown in the [COMPSs Sample Application Manual](http://compss.bsc.es/releases/compss/latest/docs/Sample_Applications.pdf). I have added the -m flag to enable the monitoring feature:

```
$ runcompss -m --debug increment.Increment 5 1 2 3
```

The application runs and finishes properly (no error shown in the std output/error and the runtime.log inside the .COMPSs folder hasn't got any stack trace).

I have also started the COMPSs Monitor service running the following command (I also add its output)

```
$ /etc/init.d/compss-monitor start
* Starting COMPSs Monitor
* Checking JAVA Installation...
   Success
* Checking IT_HOME...
WARNING: IT_HOME not defined. Trying default location /opt/COMPSs/
   Success
* Checking IT_MONITOR...
     IT_MONITOR=/root/.COMPSs/
   Success
* Checking COMPSs Monitor Port...
Warning: COMPSs_MONITOR_PORT not defined.
  Loading from configuration file.
      COMPSs_MONITOR_PORT=8080
   Success
* Checking COMPSs Monitor Timeout...
Warning: COMPSs_MONITOR_TIMEOUT not defined.
  Loading from configuration file.
      COMPSs_MONITOR_TIMEOUT=20000
   Success
* Configuring COMPSs Monitor service...
   Success
root's password:
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/COMPSs/Tools/monitor/apache-tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/COMPSs/Tools/monitor/apache-tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/COMPSs/Tools/monitor/apache-tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib64/jvm/jdk1.7.0_71/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/COMPSs/Tools/monitor/apache-tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/COMPSs/Tools/monitor/apache-tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

However, when I open the monitor webpage I can't select any application execution because the left menu is empty (see image).

[image: COMPSs Monitor main page - empty application selector]

Does anyone know how if I need to configure something more to display the COMPSs monitor? Am I missing any other flag to the runcompss command or on the environment?

Comment: Have you checked if the user used to log in the monitor is the same than the one you use to run the application?

Comment: I have logged in the monitor without specifying any user. However, when I use my user the applications appear. So I guess the default user for the monitor is not right. Do you know how can I change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The COMPSs Monitor has an environment variable that points to the folder that will be used to load the executed applications. You can modify its default value by editing the `compss-monitor.conf` file. For example, you can run:

```
$ sudo vi /opt/COMPSs/Tools/monitor/apache-tomcat/conf/compss-monitor.conf
IT_MONITOR=/home/yourUSER/.COMPSs/

$ /etc/init.d/compss-monitor restart
```

By default this variable is pointing to the `/root/.COMPSs` folder. In the case you described, the monitor is loading the executed applications from this folder instead of `/home/yourUSER/.COMPSs/` folder (and that is why you can't see any application's execution).

If you are not willing to modify the default value of this variable remember that you can log in to the monitor (in the wellcome page) using unix user or an absolute path.

For more information please check: [COMPSs Application Execution Manual](http://compss.bsc.es/releases/compss/latest/docs/COMPSs_User_Manual_App_Exec.pdf), Section 4.2. COMPSs Monitor.